# Этимология слова "тумак"

Tags: этимология

Откуда происходит слово "тумак" и является ли оно жаргонизмом?

Comment: Этимология достоверно неизвестна. Можно посмотреть здесь: http://endic.ru/fasmer/Tumak-13958.html